# Exclude missing values from lm function without NaN

Tags: r, nan, missing-data, lm

I'm running a linear regression (lm) on three variables and need to separate it per treatment and per soil type. My output is individual summaries for each soil*treatment combination which I will use to make a panel of contour maps. I can do this by using my raw dataset with no missing data, but the outliers skew the data. I'd like to know how I can run this code to exclude the missing values.

I've subset the larger dataset to include only the columns I want and to exclude two of the treatments in each soil type (this works with or without specifying the factor and numeric aspects):

```
CropSub <- subset(Pots1, !Treatment %in% c("Control1", "Control2"), 
select = c(as.factor(Soil), as.factor(Treatment), as.numeric(Drywt), as.numeric(Nrecovery),
as.numeric(Precovery)), na.action = function(x) x[, complete.cases(x)])
```

I then run the lm model by soil and treatment type individually:

```
CropMod1 <- by(CropSub, list(CropSub$Soil, CropSub$Treatment), function(df) {
  CropMod1_lm <- lm(Drywt ~ Nrecovery + Precovery, data=df, na.action=na.exclude)
return(CropMod1_lm)
})
```

This all works fine when running a summary on the soil*treatment combinations where there is no missing data, but as soon as a treatment shows a missing value in any of my selected variables, I get the following output:

```
summary(CropMod1[["Haverhill", "CanolaMeal10thaTSP"]])
```

[image]

In case the image doesn't show, the coefficients table shows NaN values for the standard error, t value & Pr(>|t|) values:

> Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|) (Intercept)  9.44438        NaN
> NaN      NaN Nrecovery    0.09192        NaN     NaN      NaN
> Precovery    0.04506        NaN     NaN      NaN

To exclude the missing values I have tried the following with no change in the result:

- add 'na.strings = ""' during the csv call
- replace all blanks in my dataset with NA
- leaving out or replacing 'na.action = na.exclude' in the lm call with na.omit, and a complete.cases argument
- leaving out or replacing the complete.cases argument in the subsetting function with na.exclude, na.omit.
- na.rm=TRUE doesn't work with the subset or lm functions.
- using `CropSub1 <- subset(CropSub, !is.na(Drywt) & !is.na(Nrecovery) & !is.na(Precovery))` to exclude the missing data
- using `CropSub <- na.exclude(CropSub)` to exclude the missing data

As an example of the data:

```
data <- data.frame(
  Soil = c("Haverhill", "Haverhill", "Haverhill", "Haverhill", "Haverhill", "Haverhill", "Haverhill", "Haverhill", "Oxbow", "Oxbow", "Oxbow", "Oxbow", "Oxbow", "Oxbow", "Oxbow", "Oxbow"),
  Treatment = c("CanolaMeal10thaTSP", "CanolaMeal10thaTSP", "CanolaMeal10thaTSP", "CanolaMeal10thaTSP", "Manure10thaTSP", "Manure10thaTSP", "Manure10thaTSP", "Manure10thaTSP", "CanolaHull10tha", "CanolaHull10tha", "CanolaHull10tha", "CanolaHull10tha", "Willow10tha", "Willow10tha", "Willow10tha", "Willow10tha"),
  Drywt = c(NA, 10.75, 10.69, 10.81, 8.89, 9.83, 9.9, 9.31, 4.12, 4.78, 4.74, 3.75, 8.5, 4.4, 5.25, 3.45),
  Nrecovery = c(7.13, 8.9, 8.61, 9.44, 15.09, 14.32, 20.41, 18.04, NA, 20.24, 16.24, 15.9, 17.34, 14.03, 23.73, 15.56),
  Precovery = c(8.69, 10.82, 10.08, 11.05, 11.26, 11.46, 14.95, 13.94, 3.37, 22.15, 9.88, 3.78, 64.65, 15.84, 41.3, -0.47)
)
```

Comment: You could use `complete.cases` to subset out any rows that contain a NA. e.g. `data[complete.cases(data),]`

Comment: Thanks. This didn't work, but the problem seems to be in the by statement causing the model to effectively run each treatment separately. Any treatment where one of the observations have been removed now only has three datapoints, causing the degrees of freedom in the model to be zero.